# ANN Training Set Scaling

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I am working on an ANN using Backpropagation at the moment, for a classification task. I am however a little confused about normalizing the data set I am using(I do not have a strong stats/probability background).

A sample of the data is shown below:

```
5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 1
5.2, 2.7, 3.9, 1.4, 2
5.9, 3.0, 5.1, 1.8, 3
```

Where the last token of each is the class.

Now, as I am using the Sigmoid transfer function, my network obviously cannot output a value greater than 1, so the data needs to be normalized/scaled.

My first question; would I need to scale both the features and the class, or just the class?

My second question, is there any 'de-facto' or commonly used method of doing such scaling?

Regards,
Jack Hunt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually recommended to also scale the features. Scaling should be as straightforward as scaled_feature = (feature - min(featurearray))/(max(featurearray) - min(featurearray)).

So for the first attribute column, the new data would be:
(5.1-5.1)/(5.9-5.1);
(5.2-5.1)/(5.9-5.1);
(5.9-5.1)/(5.9-5.1)

Comment: Actually, this should be (feature - min) / (max - min)

Comment: @Alptigin Jalayr Hi, so would I normalize by attribute, as in your example, or normalize by an attribute set? Thanks.

Comment: By each Attribute, as in the scaling example above. Not sure what you mean by attribute set (Do you mean each 'row'?).

Comment: @AlptiginJalayr Hi, yes, I meant by row. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Np. The insight into this lies in the definition of Normalization. Say you have 2 columns, heights and weights. All the heights would be samples of the same normal distribution, and hence the normalization would have to be done for them collectively. Similarly, all the weights would be normalized by calculating the mean and standard deviation for the weights column.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the topic of scaling is one of the most important aspects in employing machine learning algorithms, especially ANNs.

Yes, the (feature-min / max - min) approach is one possibility.

However, there are a range of other methods.  For example, you could use z-scores (in terms of standard deviations from the mean).  Alternatively, there is also a technique called z-axis normalization, in which an extra component is added to a normalized vector.  And sometimes, absolutely no scaling is required.

Comment: z-scores don't work for sigmoid activation functions, though, since for non-tiny data sets they're pretty much guaranteed to include values outside [-1, 1].